# Printing a frame in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to implement a function that prints a frame in python.It should print some thing like this when given two integers,4 and 7 and the char '$' for example

```
$$$$$$$
$     $
$     $
$$$$$$$
```

So far I can only do this

```
$$$$$$$
$     
$     
$$$$$$$
```

So my problem now is on how to cover the remaining side of the frame.Here is my current code

```
def print_frame(n, m, c):
    for i in range(1,m):
         print(c,end = " ")


    for d in range(1,n):
        print(c)

    for i in range(1,m+1):
        print(end = "")


    for i in range(1,m+1):
         print(c,end = " ")
```

(Note.This is a homework problem but it is a bonus problem(solving it is optional))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the middle section, add some spacing:

```
for d in range(1, n - 1):
    print(c + ' ' * (m - 2) + c)
```

or use:

```
for d in range(1, n - 1):
    print(c, ' ' * (m - 2), c, sep='')
```

Note that you need to loop `n - 2` times too, the top and bottom lines should not be part of the count here.

The `print(end='')` loop is entirely redundant; that just prints nothing.

Complete function:

```
def print_frame(n, m, c):
    print(c * m)
    for i in range(1, n - 1):
        print(c, ' ' * (m - 2), c, sep='')
    print(c * m)
```

Quick demo:

```
>>> def print_frame(n, m, c):
...     print(c * m)
...     for i in range(1, n - 1):
...         print(c, ' ' * (m - 2), c, sep='')
...     print(c * m)
... 
>>> print_frame(5, 6, '*')
******
*    *
*    *
*    *
******
```

Comment: This really helped me shorten my code and solve the problem,especially,print(c*m) which I had forgotten altogether.This really opened up my mind,thanks